# Finitely additive function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a finite-cofinite field on an infinite set.
>   Define $P:\mathcal{F}\to\{0,1\}$ by $$P(A)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } |A|<\infty\\ 1 & \text{ otherwise}\\ \end{cases}$$
>
> Show that $P$ is finitely additive.

My attempt:

Take any two disjoint sets, $E,F\in\mathcal{F}$. Then $|E\sqcup F|<\infty$ if and only if $|E|<\infty$ and $|F|<\infty$. If $|E|<\infty$ and $|F|\not<\infty$, or $|E|\not<\infty$ and $|F|<\infty$, $|E\sqcup F|\not<\infty$. In these cases, it is clear that $P(E\sqcup F)=P(E)+P(F)$.

The problem I have is that when $|E|$ and $|F|$ are both infinite, $P(E\sqcup F)=1$ and $P(E)+P(F)\neq 1$. So why must $P$ be finitely additive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only required to have $P(E\cup F)=P(E)+P(F)$ if $E$ and $F$ are *disjoint*. It follows from the definition of $\mathcal F$ that if $E\cap F=\emptyset$ then ...

Comment: Is it not possible to have two disjoint cofinite sets $E$ and $F$?

Comment: @woofy Try to think of an example, say on $\mathbb  N$.

Comment: @woofy Then, when you give up: Suppose $E,F\subset X$. Show that $E\cap F=\emptyset$ if and only if $E$ is a subset of ... .

Comment: Ah! I get it. $E$ must be a subset of $X-F$. But $X-F$ is finite. Thanks for your help.