# Prove that a given measure on the co-finite field is finitely additive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\Omega$ is countably infinite and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the co-finite field. Define a measure $\mu$ on the field such that
$$\mu(A)=\begin{cases}0\quad\text{if, }A\text{ finite}\\1\quad\text{if, }A^c\text{ finite}\end{cases}$$
Show that $\mu$ is a finitely additive measure.

**My attempt.** What we know from $\Omega$ being countably infinite is that one of $A$ and $A^c$ must be infinite and one, finite within the field. Proving this for the case when all $A_i$'s (assumed disjoint) are finite is easy. For the other case, suppose $A_i$'s not finite for some $i\in I\subseteq\{1,...,n\}$. Then, ${A_i}^c$ finite for all $i\in I$. Now, we see observe that $\cup^nA_i$ is not finite but $(\cup^nA_i)^c=\cap^n{A_i}^c\subseteq\cap_{i\in I}{A_i}^c$, which is finite. So, $\mu(\cup^nA_i)=1$. However, $\sum^n\mu(A_i)=\sum_{i\in I}\mu(A_i)=|I|\ge1$ (i.e. may be $>1$ depending on $I$). Where am I going wrong?

There is a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2577932/562589), but it doesn't clear my doubt or I failed to understand it, if it is suppopsed to.

Comment: What do you mean by "$\Omega$ is countably additive"? Do you mean that $\Omega$ is an infinite countable set?

Comment: When you write "let $\mathcal{F}$ be the co-finite field", I think you mean $\mathcal{F}$ is the finite-cofinite field. Is that correct?

Comment: $\Bbb N$ is countable, but if $A$ is the set of even numbers in it, neither $A$ nor $A^c$ are finite. So $\Omega$ being countably infinite does not tell us $A$ or $A^c$ is finite. I presume that $A \in \cal F$ is what tells us that.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint sets in $\cal F$, then $B \subset A^c$. So if $A$ is infinite, what does that say about $B$?

Comment: @Ramiro Yes and yes.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, that is what i meant i.e. for $A\in\mathcal{F}$, exactly one of $A,A^c$ is infinite and the other finite. This also requires the assumption that $\Omega$ is countably infinite.

Comment: I realized that just after I posted, and was editing. However, there is no need for $\Omega$ to be countable, only infinite is needed to be able to say for $A\in \cal F$ that exactly one of $A, A^c$ is finite. In fact, countability of $\Omega$ is not needed for this exercise as all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\Omega$ is countably infinite and $\mathcal{F}$ is  the finite-cofinite field.

Let $A_1,..., A_n \in \mathcal{F}$ be disjoint sets. If there is at least one $j \in \{1,..,n\}$ such that $A_j$ is not finite, then we have that $A_j$ is cofinite, that is $A_j^c$ is finite. Since $A_1,..., A_n$ are disjoint sets, for all $i\neq j$, $A_i \subseteq A_j^c$, and so $A_i$ is finite. It means, there is only one $j \in \{1,..,n\}$ such that $A_j$ is not finite.
Now, since $\left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)^c= \bigcap _{i=1}^n A_i \subseteq A_j^c$, we have that $\left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)^c$ is finite too. That means $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ is cofinite.  So we have
$$ \mu \left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)= 1 = 1 +0 = \mu(A_j)+ \sum_{\substack { i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^n \mu(A_i)$$

Comment: Ah, so you basically proved that it is only possible to have at most 1 element in $I$? Thank you for your answer~